# Live CD crashes when removing it after installation

Tags: live-cd

I installed ubuntu just some minutes ago. It said Installation finished, you need to restart your computer. Okay when installation finished then what's there any need of a cd in the drive.

So I removed it and the screen gone blank and hanged. Mouse pointer now not moving. I put cd again and forcefully restarted the computer then it came up with installation option again. I hated this. Then again I removed the cd from drive and forcefully restarted computer and now I'm on my ubuntu desktop.

I want your comments. Is everything well? All seems to be normal now but I still want to talk with you. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything sounds normal to me.  While the live Linux system is shutting down, it reads off the CD for the shutdown programs, and when that's done, it prompts you to remove the disk for restart.

Since it's a read-only system on the CD, there's no danger of shutdown while in the middle of doing something, which is probably stuff like seeing if it needs to write logfiles (it doesn't), shut down servers gracefully (who cares, they don't save their state), etc.

So, don't worry, be happy. :)  Enjoy your new system.

PS.  Don't be afraid of problems; consider them to be challenges.  You'll learn a lot more that way, like it or not. :)

Comment: I wish everything is normal now. First time I installed ubuntu some 20 days ago. Then I let cd remain in the drive while restarting. Now as I removed it before restart, whatever, Ubuntu seems like running lot faster than previous installation :)
And thanks for your last line :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you successfully got to your desktop, I would assume that everything is alright now.

When you first removed the disk, did you wait for the computer to tell you when to remove it? Once it says you will need to restart, if you go ahead and tell it to restart, it will eventually tell you to remove the installation medium and then you are good to go.

Like I said, since you made it to the desktop, it sounds like everything is cool. Have fun with Ubuntu!