# Ubuntu starts a bit unexpectedly

Tags: installation, startup

When I first installed Ubuntu 20 days ago, it started like a purple screen appears with Ubuntu written and loading points and then the login screen. But now when it starts, it is like a purple screen appears and after 2 seconds it goes off and again it appears with Ubuntu written and loading points. Is this normal behavior?

This time when I installed Ubuntu I removed CD from the drive before restarting. I didn't let Ubuntu to first restart and then remove CD.

Is that behavior related to this happening? This CD thing I've explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198711/live-cd-crashes-when-removing-it-after-installation). Please explain me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont fix it if it ain't broken.

So if it starts without giving you trouble and works without an issue, then dont let that purple screen bother you. This is not related to you removing the CD and if the Ubuntu setup said that it finished with success then it doesnt make a difference whether you remove the CD before or after restart.

Comment: Thanks. For me both answers are correct but due to rules I can only select one.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a problem at all. My Ubuntu starts in blank and at the final stage the spash is shown and then I presented with the Login screen. So, if you aren't experiencing other problem, I would suggest you to ignore this issue.

> This time when I installed ubuntu I removed CD from the drive before restarting. I didn't let Ubuntu to first restart and then remove CD

Actually you need to remove Ubuntu CD before restarting, i.e after clicking the restart button (after installation is finished) you will be asked to remove the CD. And technically speaking, there is no harm in removing the CD if your installation says, it finished with success. So, no need to worry about it.

Comment: "... i.e after clicking the restart button (after installation is finished) you will be asked to remove the CD."
Who thinks that way? I thought after I click restart button, it'll restart without asking me anything that's why I removed it before my computer goes to turn off. I never (and in no way) can have this in my mind that it'll ASK it. Whatever thanks for your information :) It helped.